# MS Chart in WPF, Setting the DataSource is not creating the Series

Tags: wpf, mschart

Here I am trying to assign the datasource (using same code given in the sample application) and create a graph, only difference is i am doing it in WPF WindowsFormsHost. due to some reason the datasource is not being assigned properly and i am not able to see the series ("Series 1") being created. wired thing is that it is working in the Windows Forms application but not in the WPF one.

am i missing something and can somebody help me?

Thanks

```
<Window x:Class="SEDC.MDM.WinUI.WindowsFormsHostWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms" 
  xmlns:CHR="clr- namespace:System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Forms.Dat  aVisualization"
  Title="HostingWfInWpf" Height="230" Width="338">
  <Grid x:Name="grid1">
  </Grid>
  </Window>


private void drawChartDataBinding()
{
System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host =
new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
string fileNameString = @"C:\Users\Shaik\MSChart\WinSamples\WinSamples\data\chartdata.mdb";

// initialize a connection string 
string myConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileNameString;

// define the database query 
string mySelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM REPS;";

// create a database connection object using the connection string 
OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(myConnectionString);

// create a database command on the connection using query 
OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection);
Chart Chart1 = new Chart();
// set chart data source
Chart1.DataSource = myCommand;

// set series members names for the X and Y values 
Chart1.Series"Series 1".XValueMember = "Name";
Chart1.Series"Series 1".YValueMembers = "Sales";

// data bind to the selected data source
Chart1.DataBind();

myCommand.Dispose();
myConnection.Close();
host.Child = Chart1;
this.grid1.Children.Add(host); 
}
```

Shaik

Comment: I haven't used MS Chart in years, so hopefully a MS Chart expert will come to your aid. Have you tried the DataVisualizationToolkit in the free WPFToolkit on CodePlex? It is in some ways much more advanced than MS Chart, and it certainly fits in better with WPF.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it, but the performance is not that good and it locks up randomly, moreover it is not proven. The reason i wanted to try MSChart is that MS bought it from Duddas. Any ways amCharts looks promising and it is cheap too

Answer (score 0):

With the following two changes, you can fix your code:

1 - Instead of

```
Chart1.Series"Series 1".XValueMember = "Name"; 
Chart1.Series"Series 1".YValueMembers = "Sales";
```

write

```
Chart1.Series["Series 1"].XValueMember = "Name"; 
Chart1.Series["Series 1"].YValueMembers = "Sales";
```

2 - Before the above code, insert the following lines:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas.Add("Default");
Chart1.Series.Add(new Series("Series 1"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, first i made a mistake while pasting the code, it copied the "[" as double quotes .
Any way manually adding the Chart areas and Series would work, it was wokring for me earlier, but setting the Datasource should create the Chart Area and the Series automatically, which is not.